# React.js - 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression' error in return

Tags: reactjs

Here is the piece of code that is giving me trouble:

```
records.map((record, index) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="object-preview"
                onClick={(event) => {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  setFeaturedResult(record);
                    record.primaryimageurl
                    ? `<img src=${record.primaryimageurl} alt=${record.description}/>`
                    : null;
                    
                  record.title
                    ? `<h3> ${record.title} </h3>`
                    : "<h3>MISSING INFO</h3>";
                }}
              />
            );
          })
```

And I am recieving the error message for lines 87 and 90 (record.primaryimageurl and record.title respectively). Am I not returning it properly? Thanks!

Comment: You need a `return` statement to return data from a bracket enclosed function. I'm not sure what the goal is here though, React doesn't do anything with the return from an `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You display your JSX in the `onClick` function, I guess you want to display it in the `div`.

```
return records.map((record, index) => {
    return (
        <div
            key={index}
            className="object-preview"
            onClick={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                setFeaturedResult(record);
            }}
        >
            <>
                {record.primaryimageurl && <img src={record.primaryimageurl} alt={record.description} />}
                <h3>{record.title || "MISSING INFO"} </h3>
            </>
        </div>
    );
})
```